# live/hot reload does not work on a dockerized nestJS API

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs, reload, hot-reload

I'm experiencing a strange problem, I'm currently using windows 10 and running docker via WSL2, I cloned the repository in my windows file manager and I'm trying to run it in DEV, that is, as soon as I update a file in my local repository this change is reflected within the container, but this is not happening, I have tried different ways.

My dockerfile is like this

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /src

ADD package.json /src 

RUN npm i --silent

ADD . /src 

RUN npm run build 

CMD npm start
```

Then I build this image with docker build -t test .

After that I try to upload docker-compose which is as follows.

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        build: .
        command: npm run start:dev
        ports:
            - 4000:4000
        volumes:
            - .:/src/
            - /src/node_modules

volumes:
    nodemodules: {}
```

And even doing a docker-compose up --build, when I change a file it doesn't reload automatically.

But when I clone and repeat all the steps correctly in the repository below, the live/hot reload works normally.

[https://github.com/ThomasOliver545/nestjs-local-development-docker-compose-hot-reload](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

These are my dependencies in this project (new project).

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "28.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.8",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
```

What am I doing wrong?

I just need the live/hot reload to work.

**Update guys**... I just created a VM with ubuntu and ran the same code that was running on my windows and the hot/live reload worked correctly, apparently there is no way to make the container notice changes in the code present in the storage area work from windows into the container.

Comment: How does Docker fit into this setup?  Can you use Node directly on your host, without involving a Docker container (and without Docker's filesystem isolation features)?

Comment: My main idea is to expand the project, that is, create the database, put it on the same network... I left only the API because I want to make it work for my context first, which is a live reaload of the application mapped from my directory -> inside from the container.

Comment: You can use a Docker-based database in combination with an otherwise host-based development environment, and I've found that a pretty effective way to get a temporary database if I need one.

Comment: Worse than my biggest problem is just the hot reload, I want to solve this first, to be able to implement a database.

Comment: I need what happens in this video to happen at minute 58:37

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIyZEC76a98&t

Comment: In short, guys, I need an example of a NESTJS application in this latest version 9 dockerized with hot/live reload working (ie, saving a file locally and the container restarting) in a windows environment with WSL2.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue came from the version of typescript and the usage of docker in dev with windows.
In the github link you posted, the version is ^3.7.4 so here 3.10.1.
In your code, the version is "^4.7.4" and so 4.9 can be installed.
Since 4.9 typescript, the watcher checks file changes using the system’s native events for file changes [see the release](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#file-watching-now-uses-file-system-events).
This cause an issue with windows and docker mounting volume [see issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4739).

To adjust your code you can downgrade to a previous version or you can keep the last release ( I suggest you this one ). To do so, follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75318862/nestjs-doesnt-hot-reload-work-in-inside-docker/75789242#75789242)

Answer (score 0):

Move your project to WSL2 filesystem instead of Windows filesystem