# NESTJS API dockerized with hot/live reaload in version 9 of nest

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

In short, guys, I need an example of a NESTJS application in this latest version 9 dockerized with hot/live reload working (ie, saving a file locally and the container restarting) in a windows environment with WSL2.

I open one issue here about this [live/hot reload does not work on a dockerized nestJS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74637332/live-hot-reload-does-not-work-on-a-dockerized-nestjs-api)

**Update guys**... I just created a VM with ubuntu and ran the same code that was running on my windows and the hot/live reload worked correctly, apparently there is no way to make the container notice changes in the code present in the storage area work from windows into the container.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Man, I basically need a tutorial like the guy sent below, but that works. because the hot/live reload doesn't work at all for me.